# How to sum rows in the same column than the category in pandas dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on formatting a log file and finally I have arrived to the following dataframe sample, where the categories and numbers I want to add are in the same column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=['Cat. A',1,1,3,'Cat. A',2,2,'Cat. B',3,5,2,6,'Cat. B',1,'Cat. C',4]))
>>> a
0   Cat. A
1   1
2   1
3   3
4   Cat. A
5   2
6   2
7   Cat. B
8   3
9   5
10  2
11  6
12  Cat. B
13  1
14  Cat. C
15  4
```

If I sum all the numbers below each category I want to obtain:

```
Cat. A= 1+1+3+2+2 = 9
Cat. B= 3+5+2+6+1 = 17
Cat. C= 4
```

I know how to do with going through all the files in the classic way, but I would like to know how to do it in a most pythonic way, considering that the numbers of rows for each category can be variable, and that the numbers of times that the category appears in each dataframe can be different too.

Comment: please provide a dataframe with hardcoded values. [edit] your [mre]. thanks

Comment: here `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=['Cat. A',1,1,3,'Cat. A',2,2,'Cat. B',3,5,2,6,'Cat. B',1,'Cat. C',4]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to mark non-numeric fields as `nan` using [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) then use for group. Then use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

```
a = pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce')
g = df['a'].mask(a.notna()).ffill()
a.groupby(g).sum()

Cat. A     9.0
Cat. B    17.0
Cat. C     4.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6):

This is also another way

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=['Cat. A',1,1,3,'Cat. A',2,2,'Cat. B',3,5,2,6,'Cat. B',1,'Cat. C',4]))

def coerce(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return np.nan
    except:
        return x

def safesum(x):
    return x[x!=x.iloc[0]].astype(int).sum()


df['b'] = df['a'].apply(coerce).ffill()
df.groupby('b').agg(safesum)
```

Produces

```
         a
b         
Cat. A   9
Cat. B  17
Cat. C   4
```

Answer (score 0):

In a very fiew lines, in a simple and direct way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=['Cat. A', 1, 1, 3, 'Cat. A', 2, 2, 'Cat. B', 3, 5, 2, 6, 'Cat. B', 1, 'Cat. C', 4]))

df['label'] = (df['a'].apply(lambda x: x if str(x)[0] == 'C' else None)).ffill()
df['value'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: 0 if str(x)[0] == 'C' else int(x))
result = df.groupby('label').sum()

print(result)
```

output

```
        value
label         
Cat. A       9
Cat. B      17
Cat. C       4
```

*Explanation*

`label` and 'value' columns are created and store labels and values, respectively
then use `groupby` with `sum`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. not very pythonic, but it does the work:

```
l=list(df.a)

d={i:0 for i in l if str(i)[:3]=='Cat'}

for i in l:
    if str(i)[:3]=='Cat':
        key=i
    else:
        d[key]+=i

>>> print(d)

{'Cat. A': 9, 'Cat. B': 17, 'Cat. C': 4}
```